# How to match date leaving time components out in an NSPredicate?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an NSDate with time components zeroed out.

I have an NSDate member in each object in an NSArray.

I want to filter out an array of objects using NSPredicate to keep only Objects matching the date I am using to filter.

The catch is: The date field in the object has time components which I need to be there.

How do I form a predicate format string where I am only matching the date part and not the time.

I have made a static utility method that takes in a date and gives a date with time component zeroed out.

Can I use this method inside the predicate string to convert that date and then compare ?

**Here is the code:**

```
NSDate *startingDate = [MyUtilities  dateByRemovingTimeFromDate:self.currentEvent.associatedEvent.startDate];
NSDate *filterDate = [MyUtilities dateByAddingDays:_selectedRow toDate:startingDate];
NSArray *filteredArray = nil;
filteredArray = [_eventsList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"displayDate == %@",filterDate]];
```

Can I use the method  `dateByRemovingTimeFromDate`: of `MyUtilities` that I have made inside the `predicate string` on `displayDate` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a predicate with a date range so you don't need to compare the time (or modify it)m just calculate the start and end of the day range (then use `>=` the start date and `<=` the end date).

---

```
NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"displayDate >= %@ AND displayDate <= %@", filterDate, nextDateAfterfilterDate];
```

Comment: Something like this ?

@"displayDate between %@ and %@ ",filterDate,nextDateAfterfilterDate